# Extract a set of strings from a HTML document using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, anglesharp

I am trying to extract URLs containing a specific keyword from a HTML document with LINQ using AngleSharp parser.

I came up with:

```
    static void Test(string htmlDocument)
    {
        var parser = new HtmlParser();
        var document = parser.Parse(htmlDocument);

        var links = document.All.Where(m => m.LocalName == "a" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.GetAttribute("href")) 
                                       && m.GetAttribute("href").Contains("keyword"))
                                       .Select(m => m.GetAttribute("href"));

        foreach (var link in links)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(link);

        }
    }
```

Is there a better way (easier to write or faster to run) to get the URLS into an IEnumerable or List ?

Comment: Well you call `GetAttribute()` like 3 times, do you know what the overhead is for that?  If there is overhead you might want to rethink your approach

Comment: Can I reduce the overhead but still use LINQ?

Comment: You could make a method that returns a bool and accepts whatever “m” is. That way you can call GetAttribute() once in the method and perform the rest of your checks on the local variable.

Comment: First question I would ask is how long does it take now & how often are you doing it - a couple of the basic questions to ask when trying to optimise something which works & the code is relatively clear as to what it is doing? Basically, is it even worth optimising which may impact on maintainability later.

Comment: It's just for learning purpose, I am new to using LINQ. It doesn't take much time but I want to do it the right way.

Comment: For learning purposes is OK - but an important part of coding/programming/software engineering - whatever you want to call it - is learning when to make the effort to optimize code & when there is no point. So your code, unoptimized as it is, may actually be the right way for your application even it it does call GetAttribute 3 times.

Comment: Having said that - you could use the null-conditional operator to remove 1 call to GetAttribute _"      var links = document.All.Where(m => (m.LocalName == "a") && (m.GetAttribute("href")?.Contains("music") == true)).Select(m => m.GetAttribute("href"));"_  note that the explicit check for _"== true"_ is required as the return value of ?. is bool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngleSharp documentation may be worth a read :)

```
var links = document
    .Links
    .Cast<IHtmlAnchorElement>()
    .Select(e => e.Href)
    .Where(h => h.Contains(keyword));
```

Comment: OP's question may be worth a _re-read_ :)  OP needs to filter the links